# get href of link with display:block property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's is what I'm trying to get

```
<a href="default.aspx?propid=BARN" class="topbook"></a>
```

The above link should clone the sidelink that has `display:block`

```
<a href="default.aspx?propid=FARM" class="sidelink"></a>
<a href="default.aspx?propid=HANW" class="sidelink"></a>
<a href="default.aspx?propid=BARN" class="sidelink" style="display:block"></a>
```

But I'm getting

```
<a href="default.aspx?propid=FARM" class="topbook"></a>
```

Because it is copying the first instance of sidelink `href`

Here's my code

```
$('.topbook').attr('href', $('.sidelink').attr('href'));
```

Hope this helps

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing that - give the anchor you want a different `class` or something, don't differentiate them by using the `style` attribute

Comment: The side links are dynamically put in depending on how many properties are available so i can't differentiate them by different class

Comment: @Jamie You mean it'll always be (say) the last one? Then use something like `:eq` or `:last`, or even better, since you can dynamically give them `style` s, then why can't you have the server-side script give it an additional class?

Comment: @Yi Jiang it won't necessarily be the last one all the time

Comment: @Yi Jiang how can I dynamically give them a style?

Comment: @Jamie, ah, no, I misread that comment. What I meant was that whatever server-side process that enabled you to give a specific `a` a `display: block` style should also allow you to give it a `class` in the same manner. If you want to add styles to elements with jQuery see http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Had a look at doing that - the problem being I am showing and hiding bits in an asp.Net query it only shows the data that is available

Comment: @Jamie Maybe you should ask a new question about the server-side problem. I'm not at all familiar with ASP.NET, but I can't imagine this being a difficult problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could conceivably use

```
$('.topbook').attr('href', $('.sidelink[style$="block"]').attr('href'));
```

but please don't.

Instead, give the `.sidelink` element whose `href` you're trying to copy a different class or something, don't use the `style` attribute to differentiate it from the others.

Comment: +1 
Even better than a different class is to use a unique id.